# TypeError: Components.utils is undefined in Firefox WebExtension Development

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am migrating a Firefox Add-on SDK add-on to a WebExtensions add-on. I read that I will have to use

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
```

for Services.jsm. But, I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Components.utils is undefined
```

How do I import Services module?

Comment: You cannot access XPCOM (`Components`) or `Services.jsm` directly from a webextension.  Which service(s) are you trying to get at?

Comment: I am trying to get at IO services (nsIIOService). Also, I need to get to ctypes.jsm as well.

Comment: There's a lot of stuff in nsIIOService, but if you just want to load something, you can use `fetch()` or XHR.  ctypes is out of the question for webextensions.

Comment: Ok. I need to get protocol handler Services.io.getProtocolHandler("resource").QueryInterface(Ci.nsIResProtocolHandler); How can I replace this with fetch() or XHR? I need to use ctypes to open dll using ctypes.open(dll.path); what could be the replacement for that? Can I access dll in WebExtension?

Comment: There's some basic support for protocol handlers in Firefox 54, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1310427.  Like I said in a previous comment, ctypes is not available in webextensions.  It would help if you describe what you're trying to do at a higher level, rather than how you want to do it.